# How to Pass in Store as a prop

Tags: reactjs, store, react-props

I am currently having a problem getting store to be passed in as a prop and am wondering what to label a few things.

The current error is within create store, I'm unsure what to do with it.

I have tried other methods and only want to use the store method where I pass it in as a prop

```
import React from 'react';
import { MockGit } from './Constants';
import ExpansionPanelSummary from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelSummary';
import ExpansionPanelDetails from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanelDetails';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore';
import ExpansionPanel from '@material-ui/core/ExpansionPanel';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import TestAPI from './TestAPI';
import { displayGitData, userInfoURL, getDataSaga } from '../sagas/sagas';
import { createStore } from 'redux';


class GitData extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    const store = createStore(...);   //this is what im unsure of.
    const { store } = this.props;
     return (

      <ExpansionPanel>
        <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
          <Typography> {MockGit} </Typography>
        </ExpansionPanelSummary>
        <ExpansionPanelDetails>
          {displayGitData()}
          {userInfoURL()}
          {getDataSaga()}
          <TestAPI />
        </ExpansionPanelDetails>
      </ExpansionPanel>
     );
   }
 }
export default GitData;
```

The goal is to get store passed in as a prop with no errors.

Any help would be great, Thanks!

Comment: What's the current error? More importantly, you shouldn't be creating the store in a component - every time the component re-renders the store will reset, which you don't want. Create the store in your index/main file, then pass it in via props if you need it, though ideally you would just `connect` to it

Comment: the store returned from `createStore()` would usually be passed to the `store` prop of [Provider](https://react-redux.js.org/api/provider). That `Provider` would be wrapped around some component to make the store available to any component nested inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it wrong, here's the recommended way to use React with Redux:

#### store.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';
export default createStore(...)
```

#### index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store.js'

const App = () => (<h1>Hello from App</h1>);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><App/></Provider>
  document.querySelector('#react-root')
);
```

You now have an app that is bound with the store.

The `react-redux` npm package allows also to bind component props to store dispatches and store state, example:

#### my-component.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <p>{this.props.hello}</p>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(state => ({hello: state.helloReducer.value}))(MyComponent)
```

For further tutorials, check the official docs of react-redux, or [this good youtube playlist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qrsle5quS7A&list=PL55RiY5tL51rrC3sh8qLiYHqUV3twEYU_).